# Node-Neo4j-Embedded limits (call for new benchmark)

Tags: node.js, graph, neo4j, orientdb, arangodb

Is there anybody out there using [Node-Neo4j-embedded](https://github.com/joewhite86/node-neo4j-embedded/tree/neo4j-2.x) in production mode ?

**What kind of limits are expectable ?**

Because I think this module is pushing the `Cypher` queries directly to the `node-java` module, what uses them directly with Neo4j java libs, I belief there shouldn't be any limits.

I feel it is dangerous to decide to use a lib what isn't maintained for about 2 years (see: [github](https://github.com/joewhite86/node-neo4j-embedded/tree/neo4j-2.x)) - and it shouldn't be on [Neo4j docs](http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/#_other_drivers) if it isn't maintained (see: README.md dead link about API-Docs).

It looks like there could be a new trend to power up node.js support like first citizen languages by [other distributor(s)](http://orientdb.com/welcome-to-orientjs/) for (in_memory) graph databases. Maybe Neo4j also should review this and the unmaintained node module (like OrentDB did). The trend had bin initiated by a [benchmark-battle](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-performance-challenge/) between [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/2015/07/multi-model-benchmark-round-1/) and OrientDB.

I would love to see an Node-Neo4j-embedded benchmark answer to the open source benchmark of ArangoDB - done by professional Neo4j people like OrientDB people had done. But note: They hadn't been fair enough (read the last lines about enabling [query caches](http://orientdb.com/orientdb-performance-challenge/)...).

Or it has to be a new benchmark focused on most possible first citizens-like access by NodeJS. There are three possible solutions to test. I am not experienced enough to do such a test what would be really acceptable. But I would like to help by verifying this.

**Please support this call for action with comments and (several types of) answers. A better (native like access) and wider range of supporting in_memory and graph solutions would help the node community very much. A new benchmark would force innovation**

---

**Short note about ArangoDBs benchmark**: *They've tested the REST-APIs. But if you think about performance, you don't like to use a REST-API - you like to use direct library access.*

---

@editors: you are welcome

Comment: awesome. YES that would be very cool. Better support for NodeJS by Neo4j as first citizen. I didn't use it because of Node-Neo4j-embedded wasn't maintained and the REST API seams to be much slower than library access as discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/uLV-EmlCsdc

Comment: Is it possible there is no need for this ? I cannot see much vote ups or comments. Any idea what is the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

We (ArangoDB) think that the scalability of embedded databases is to limited. It also limits the number of databases which you may want to compare. Users prefer to implement their solutions in their Application stack of choice, so you would limit the number of people potentially interested in your comparison.

The better way of doing this is to compare the officialy supported interface of the database vendor into the client stack that is commonly supported amongst all players in the field. This is why we have chosen nodejs.

There is [enough chatter about benchmarks and how to compare them on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=benchmark), so in doubt, start out to create a usecase and implement code for it, present your results in a reproducable way and request that for comment, instead of demanding others to do this for you.